# HP 630 notebook loosing battery charge without any reason

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I have a HP 630 notebook that runs on Windows 7. I think its loosing battery without any reason. I felt so because, its not showing the same battery charge level when switched on. So I decided to check it.

So yesterday I charged the notebook to 100%, switched it off and then I unplugged it. This morning I plugged it first and then switched it on. When I looked at the battery icon, it has only 88% battery charge. Where does the battery charge gone ? Why does this happens ?  Is this solvable ?

Comment: Are you certain you are turning it off instead of setting it to hibernate or sleep? Check your power settings.

Comment: @surfmadpig I am turning it off(shut down).